# WPF PathGeometry rendering

Tags: wpf, performance, profiling, rendering, hardware-acceleration

I have a PathGeometry containg a single polyline, and at a fixed interval I add a new point to the line (to plot a waveform). When using the Perforator tool I can see that every time I add a point to the line, WPF marks the entire PathGeometry as 'dirty', causing the entire shape to be re-rendered.

I hoped it would only redraw the single pixel. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: Are you actually encountering a performance issue? How many points are there in the polyline?

Comment: @Clemens I'm just doing a feasibility study to decide which technology to use for this plotter application (Winforms/D3D/WPF), so I have not yet encountered a performance issue, since I'm testing with a single line, but the final application will have much more lines. The fact that it has to redraw such a large part of the screen instead of a single pixel, makes me worried.

Comment: Then you should not stop at Path/PathGeometry, but also take low-level rendering into account. Take a look at the [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx) article. Also, rendering by means of a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) might be worth to look at.

Comment: Having said that, you should also investigate a real-world example. Do the rendering with many lines and evaluate the real performance. WPF rendering benefits from hardware acceleration, which may make it much more performant than WinForms, even if it often has to redraw a whole visual layer. You may also take a look at [Optimizing WPF Application Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970683.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No..

WPF is correct in dirtying the entire geometry upon a change as it take into consideration a situation where current path values had changes as well.

If you break this down, you can use a list of lines instead of path.. but,
That would mean you will have to update the lines values each time the user resize your plotting area in order to keep your proportions..

So to handle this you would probably write some code that says:
"if user resized - dirty all lines"..

Another issue is when you add another line,
you might want to squeeze all your lines to fit into your plotting area,
So you would probably write some code that says:
"if new line add - dirty all lines"..

which now give path geometry behavior a 1 to 1 similarity to your mini-engine..

If you don't need to or want to handle resizings or refittings in new lines add,
Simply use a list of lines.